# php classes relation and how to extend classes

Tags: php, oop, class

my query is about architecture and relation of classes, I would like to know better solution than I have implemented.

I have 4 classes , explaining one line for each

1. core.php class which will have all common functions
2. A.php class file which contains specific function for task A like writing on csv file A.
3. B.php class file which contains specific function for task B like writing another csv file which is totally different from csv A.
4. X.php class which is another task specific class.

Now come to general script which will use all 4 classes. so I am not understanding which class will extend which another class

No relation between A.php and B.php

But x.php must use all 3 classes core.php, A.php and B.php.

currently what I have done , I design one interface for core class, and x.php extend core class and implement interface. I design A.php and B.php as static classes.

Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have to* `extend` classes if they have nothing to do with each other. You can simply *use* one class inside another without those two having any relationship inheritance or interface-wise.

You may structure it like this:

- `class Common` is your *base class* that every class inherits from and contains common code that all classes need, say code for logging or database access.
- `class A extends Common` and is specialized for some CSV-related tasks. This class may or may not actually do anything by itself.
- `class B extends A` and is even more specialized to some specific task involving CSV.
- `class X extends Common` and is again some other task.

Generally, if a class does almost the same but slightly more specialized or differently, `extend` a common base class. If a class has nothing at all in common with another, just make them standalone classes. Use `interfaces` for polymorphism; it doesn't sound like that's what you need right now.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like basic dependency management. I don't understand why you explicitly want to extend anything though?

What you probably should do instead is inject the needed dependencies. Instantiate `Core`, `A` and `B` separately before instantiating `X` with the objects it's dependent on.